# "mittlerweile" = now / nowadays?

Tags: adverb

I have read the following question in [German Quora](https://de.quora.com/Ist-Deutschland-mittlerweile-vollst%C3%A4ndig-amerikanisiert):

> Ist Deutschland mittlerweile vollständig amerikanisiert?

According to [Word Reference](https://www.wordreference.com/deen/mittlerweile), "mittlerweile" means "in the meantime", "meanwhile", but those translations to English don't make sense in this context because there's no previously mentioned time period in which the action being mentioned now occurs. In English, one would only use "meanwhile" if there was one, e.g. "She spent two hours cleaning the house. In the meantime, I bought the ingredients for the dinner"

[Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/mittlerweile) only provides the same meanings.

[DeepL Translate](https://www.deepl.com/en/translator#de/en/Ist%20Deutschland%20mittlerweile%20vollst%C3%A4ndig%20amerikanisiert%3F) translates "mittlerweile" as "now" in this context. It seems to me another good translation would be "nowadays" (i.e. it's being used as a synonym of " "heutzutage"). Is that right?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Mittlerweile has [two meanings](https://www.duden.de/node/152860/revision/152896):

1. Referring to the end of something that has occurred over time.
   **Possible translations**: *by now, gradually, since then*
   **Example**: "Sie sollten *mittlerweile* Zuhause (angekommen) sein." - "They should be home *by now*."
2. Referring to something that is happening at the same time as  as something else.
   **Possible translations:** *in the meantime, meanwhile*
   **Example**: "Das Flugzeug ist soeben gelandet. Im Terminal laufen *mittlerweile* die Vorbereitungen auf Hochtouren." - "The plane has just landed. *In the meantime*, preparations are going ahead at full speed in the terminal."

The question "Ist Deutschland mittlerweile vollständig amerikanisiert?" is asking about the end of a process  that has taken place during recent years ("the complete americanization") so *mittlerweile* in this case is used in the first meaning. The translation could be something like "Is Germany completely Americanized by now?" or "Did Germany gradually become completely Americanized?".

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 14):

I would translate it as "by now" in this context.

> Has Germany become completely americanized by now?

Comment: Can "Inzwischen" also have this meaning, which is totally unrelated to "meanwhile" and "in the meantime" ?

Comment: Yes, *Inzwischen* and *mittlerweile* are synonymous for me, and they can both mean *meanwhile* or *by now*.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to express "heutzutage", why not? The context of your given sentence seems to be good for "nowadays". Often you need a good appropriation instead of a plain translation.

"Mitterweile" actually focuses more on the change, "heutzutage" focuses on a special and fixed time range, but in your example it's OK.

Comment: What change? "In the meantime" implies no change, but rather simultaneity, as the example in my question and https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/meantime show. Isn't that what "mittlerweile" means?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista In my feeling of language, "mittlerweile" describes a change of time from a former date to today. "Heutzutage" just describes a time we have now without starting from a former point. Not sure if this explains it pretty well.